# Rowlink in ember js

Tags: ember.js

I want to give link to an entire row.
I searched several examples but they all have given link to a single `<td>`.

Here is what I have tried:

```
         <table class="table">  
           <thead>  
             <tr>  
              <th>Leave Type</th>  
              <th>Approved Leaves</th>  
              <th>Balance Leaves</th>
              </tr>  
            </thead>  
            <tbody>  
             {{#each}}
             <tr>  
                <td>{{#link-to 'pastrequests' this}}{{leavetypes}}{{/link-to}}</td>  
                <td>{{approvedleaves}}</td>  
                <td>{{balanceleaves}}</td> 

              </tr>
              {{/each}}                  
            </tbody>  
           </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place the link on the `tr` element. Don't forget to specify the [`tagName`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#toc_html-tag):

```
<tbody>  
  {{#each}}
    {{#link-to 'pastrequests' this tagName='tr'}}  
      <td>{{leavetypes}}</td>  
      <td>{{approvedleaves}}</td>  
      <td>{{balanceleaves}}</td> 
    {{/link-to}}
  {{/each}}                  
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{{#link-to 'pastrequests' this}}
```

should be on the 'tr' not on 'td.

Comment: <tr>{{#link-to 'pastrequests' this}}
        <td>{{leavetypes}}</td>  
        <td>{{approvedleaves}}</td>  
        <td>{{balanceleaves}}</td> 
     {{/link-to}}
      </tr>
I have done this but it didnt wrk for me..